# I am trying to compare the retrieved tags with selected or created tags, if tag doesn't exist perfom post request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios

I have an object that contains some tags, I retrieved the list of tags to choose from but I want to create some tags before submitting the form. I am trying to use vue watch but it seems not working.
here is the code:

```js
data() {
    return {
      blog: {
        blog_title: "",
        tags: "",
        text: "",
      },
      myTags: {}
    };
  },
watch: {
    blog: {
      deep: true,
      handler: function(tag) {
      let token = localStorage.getItem("TOKEN_STORAGE_KEY");
      for(tag of this.blog.tags) {
        if (this.myTags.includes(tag)) {
          return axios.post(API_URL + "tags/", tag, {headers: { Authorization: `Token ${token}` }})
        }
      }
    }
```

note: I am using vuetify combobox:

```
<v-combobox label="Tags" :multiple="true" :return-object="false" :items="myTags" item-text="title" chips v-model="blog.tags"></v-combobox>
```

I am expecting to perform post request once I hit enter for new tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored my tag model, I was using django-category package, I replaced it with the new model, I get rid of the watch garbage code and it worked perfectly.
if you pass by this question or problem, I used

```html
class CustomSlugRelatedField(serializers.SlugRelatedField):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            obj, created = self.get_queryset().get_or_create(**{self.slug_field: data})
            return obj
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            self.fail('invalid')
```

as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203063/implementing-tags-using-django-rest-framework)

Answer (score 0):

1st - `handler: function(tag)` - `tag` here is not tag - it is the new value of `blog` - the property you set watch for.
2nd - `for(tag of this.blog.tags)` you use your inbound argument to iterate over `blog.tags`. It is probably not what you want.

So, the resulting code that should work:

```
watch: {
    blog: {
      deep: true,
      handler: function(newVal) {
      let token = localStorage.getItem("TOKEN_STORAGE_KEY");
      for(let tag of newVal.tags) {
        if (this.myTags.includes(tag)) {
          return axios.post(API_URL + "tags/", tag, {headers: { Authorization: `Token ${token}` }})
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: thank you Ivan for your answer. I edited my code as you stated, the watcher start watching every element in the blog object and started making a lot of post request, while I just need it to watch the tags. I think I have an issue with the if statement.

Comment: I tried to change my approach, by making a function inside the submitting function, the same for loop and if statement then apply the major axios request. still not working.